# How to export an Apple sound to Cubase

Tags: logic-pro, cubase, sound-libraries, exporting, importing

I'm moving my projects from Logic Pro X to Cubase. For a midi track, I used an Apple sound (Infinity strings).

I really need this sound and can't find anything similar in Cubase library (there must be some VST around, but the research is huge).

So is it possible to "extract" this Apple sound and import it to Cubase library?

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of if it’s not a third party plug in. But you could record the track and import it into Cubase... maybe you already thought of that.

Comment: If that's what you mean, the sound I'm talking about (Infinity Strings) is inside the Apple Library (under synth - synth strings). I don't know where these sounds are stored and whether they can be extracted and imported in Cubase. Maybe someone knows some kinda of synth strings that's similar, but I don't know any. I'm aware I can record the track in Logic and then export it in Cubase but I need to work in Midi.